# Should I enforce the rules or show sympathy?

Tags: professionalism, salary, law

I am employed by the traffic police and we are supposed to implement traffic rules. One day I found a man on a motorbike violating the rules. He was not wearing a helmet. I stopped him and asked for his driver's licence and found that he was driving without a licence.

He was a worker and his monthly income is I guess 12000-15000rs. That is even less than rent for a student living in hostel, but that man has a family too and he works to provide his family food. According to the rules he must pay a fine of 2000rs from his salary of 12000rs. It looks impossible to manage on only 10000rs for a whole month, so I gave him a final warning and let him go.

I want to know what I should do in that case afterwards and whether the decision I took at that time was right or not.

Comment: Not sure how being a cop over where you're from works. But over here here in US police hands warnings all the time if they do not feel like giving a ticket

Comment: i am employ in pakistan and and we are told to strictly implement rules.

Comment: You offer up a dichotomy.  Rules vs Sympathy.  Do the rules say that you cannot give a warning?

Comment: And then because he was violating the rules he killed someone. And because he was without driving license then no insurance will pay for that. And another family will starve because you didn't stop him. Sympathy is important and you may skip a parking violation but...

Comment: @JoeStrazzere  he told me to have acted strickly and at last let him go so that he would follow rule next time.

Comment: In some countries, the enforcement of the rules is explicitly given to the enforcer, so they can use their judgement in deciding if the broken rule is worth enforcing in a specific situation.  If that's not clear in your country, it is still effectively the way things are done (you could have not pulled him over).  Strict enforcement of rules has risks.  If the rules are unfair, unjust, or just nonsense, strict enforcement doesn't promote peace or prosperity.  Again, if application of the rules is too arbitrary, society suffers.  I'd do what I feel makes the world a better place.

Comment: What I might expect is to have the helmet issue be finished with a warning, but in no way would the subject be *driving* the motorcycle off without a license. Leave the bike where it is or push it - anything else is an intentional rule-violation and shows what thruth there is in "following the ruels next time"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're paid to do your job. Doing your job is expected to stop people from doing things outside the law, for numerous reasons (one is to prevent people from getting hurt). If the law establishes that vehicle's drivers need to have a driver's license, you have to enforce that by the role you play in implementing traffic rules. The driver's license certifies that the person is fit to drive a vehicle; not having it implies it (he/she) is not fit, officially, to drive.

The law applies to everyone, rich and poor. Otherwise, it's unfair. Even if you take into account that you think he earns less than a student living in a hostel, you have no way to verify that unless the driver has documentation to back it put; anyways, it'd not be fair to the people actually behaving by law.

Having said that, if the law contemplates giving warnings, it should be OK. But I'd use it exceptionally, given that traffic laws are implemented to prevent harm usually (Thanks to @Lumberjack for questioning in comments)

Comment: Is it against the rules to give a warning in OP's jurisdiction?

Comment: It's a good question i didn't ask myself. I guess i tried to answer in a general perspective... although i didn't specifically said it was against the rules, i now see it could be misleading. I'm going to edit the answer to be more clear.

Comment: Many countries allow the officer to use their discretion when addressing a person who has violated the rules of the road, depending in the severity of the violation.